# Mobile network operator vs. mobile network carrier

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between "mobile network *operator*" and "mobile network *carrier*"?

Comment: There may be a legal difference as defined in a specific law. More context needed.

Comment: Generally, a "mobile network *carrier*" refers to a services/companies that moves your mobile communications from point A to point B. "mobile network operator" could be the operating company of the phone service or a person you speak to for assistance with your service or placing a call. It would depend on context.

Comment: Thanks, the goal of my question is to understand the difference given any context.

Comment: It's a very lawyery thing, not really something fit for the site. It seems like there's a bit of a difference regarding virtual operators (which don't own or manage any physical infrastructure, instead relying on other companies), who aren't generally called "carriers", but in common speech those are fairly interchangeable.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_network_operator

Comment: @TimRomano So Wikipedia says it's the same, while other comments say it's not :/

Comment: These are legalistic terms not everyday nouns.  Their definitions will be found in relevant statutes, not in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ***no*** difference between *Mobile network operator* and *Mobile network carrier.*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_network_operator) describes it:

> A ***mobile network operator*** or MNO, also known as a wireless service provider, wireless carrier, cellular company, or ***mobile network carrier***, is a provider of services wireless communications that owns or controls all the elements necessary to sell and deliver services to an end user including radio spectrum allocation, wireless network infrastructure, back haul infrastructure, billing, customer care, provisioning computer systems and marketing and repair organizations.

However, note that the terminology differs from country to country. In India, we have 'Vodafone SIM' and not 'Vodafone carrier'. The word 'carrier' for mobile networking is not practiced here and might be in some neighborhood countries as well.

Comment: Indonesians do not use carrier. Formally they're referred to as "operator", but usually (especially in informal cases) they're referred to as "provider"

Comment: In the UK, you'd normally hear "operator", while in the US, it tends to be "carrier".